# Onscreen javascript countdown timer in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a timer that visibly ticks down the seconds (from 5 minutes or something -- though here I'm using 5 seconds just so have quicker feedback on the alert) after somebody's placed an order on my site til when they pay. If they haven't paid by the time the timer runs out, a delay_job I made will roll back the order.

I'm bad at javascript, and what I tried isn't working at all. Here's my shot at it (this is within a document.ready function):

```
function countdown() {
    setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
  };

  function myTimer() {
    var parentTr = $(this).parents("tr");
    var status = $(parentTr).find(".js-status").attr('data-status');
    if (status === 0) {
      var timeLeft = 30000;
      document.getElementById(".js-timer").html=timeLeft;
      if (timeLeft === 0) {
         alert("Time Out");
      };
    };
  };
```

In my view, I've got these lines that I was hoping the JS would pick up and use. But it isn't working. (And won't work when I arbitrarily say that var status = 0).

```
    <tr>
       <th class="js-timer"></th>
       <th class="js-status"  data-status=<%= @order.status %> ></th>
    ...
    </tr>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how to do this better?

Comment: You should have something running in document.ready that is calling your setInterval and counting down.  Right now nothing is going to ever 'change' .js-timer to get your anonymous function to call.

Comment: Confused. Isn't the "setInterval(function(){tick + 1},1000);" line doing that? (It's in document.ready). What else do I need to add? A separate function like the one on [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) page for displaying the time?

Comment: I see the purpose, but may I suggest the excellent [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) for even this simple usage.

Comment: Took me a while cause I'm clueless with javascript, but I think I get what you're saying. Is what I changed above based on your suggestion closer? I don't get how setInterval knows which variable to count down.

Comment: Closer, actually remove the countdown function and just put setInterval directly in your document ready and it will call setInterval once the DOM is loaded and that will call your myTimer function.  myTimer will also need some work, from what I can tell you neer update or set the time back to any variable.